# Is there a quick way to locate the SQLite database that my app creates?

Tags: sqlite, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, appdata, userappdatapath

I used [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertgreen/archive/2012/11/13/using-sqlite-in-windows-store-apps.aspx) as a basis for creating my SQLite tables.

Using the [SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/), I can view the created tables nicely.

However, in order to first create the connection in that tool, I had to locate the SQLite database I had created. I did a hard drive search for it, and found it in:

```
C:\Users\Clay\AppData\Local\Packages\99129e92-ebeb-4800-a0e5-
d0e43b016009_qtyjefqf75sa6\LocalState\photrax.sqlite
```

Now how in the world would I know that it was in *99129e92-ebeb-4800-a0e5-
d0e43b016009_qtyjefqf75sa6* (there are many similar Welch-looking folder names beneath C:\Users\Clay\AppData\Local\Packages, so how would I know which one it's in)?

Surely there's a more elegant way to find it than doing a global search.

Comment: I don't have a `Packages` folder under `AppData\Local\`. What do *I* do? Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C:\Users\Clay\AppData\Local\Package is where all your apps store their data and 99129e92-ebeb-4800-a0e5-
d0e43b016009 is most likely your package ID from the appx manifest. You can just use `ApplicationData.LocalFolder.Path` to get the path.

Comment: But I mean for hooking it up to the SQLite Toolbox - do I have to go on a hunting expedition down every rabbit hole (Welchy folder) each time I add a SQLite database to a project?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know SQLite Toolbox. Maybe some SQLite tools automatically find databases for you....

Comment: It's made by the SQL CE Whisperer. I'm going to see if LINQPad connects to SQLite more automatically. The nice thing about SQLite Toolbox is it is incorporated right into VS.

Comment: LINQPad is almost exactly the same in how one connects and what it shows. Has anyone ever seen SQLite Toolbox and LINQPad at the same time? If not, they may be the same "animal."